# Alternating ng-repeats

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Is there a way to alternate `ng-repeats` in AngularJS?

For instance, let's say I have two arrays.

**Array 1**

```
[a1, a2, a3, ...]
```

**Array 2**

```
[b1, b2, b3, ...]
```

I would like to display these values in an alternating fashion for medium and large screen sizes, such as...

**Output**

```
Array 1 Values    Array 2 Values
a1                b1
a2                b2
a3                b3
...               ...
```

In theory, the HTML would look like

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6"><h1 class="col-*-12">Array 1 values</h1>
    <div ng-repeat="a in arr1">
        <div class="col-*-12">{{a.value}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6"><h1 class="col-*-12">Array 2 values</h1>
    <div ng-repeat="b in arr2">
        <div class="col-*-12">{{b.value}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So for smaller screen sizes, I'd like the title and values from the Array1 to appear on top, and title and values from Array2 to appear on bottom.

**Output for small screen sizes**

```
Array 1 Values
a1 
a2
a3
...

Array 2 Values
b1
b2
b3
...
```

I'd like to avoid nesting the `ng-repeats`.  In theory, the above HTML code would be ideal, but I don't think it works since it outputs all the values in the first array and then all the values in the second array.  It would be nice if I could get the them to alternate after each value.  Maybe I could join the two arrays like so : `[a1, b1, a2, b2, ...]`, but then I think there would be an issue with getting the titles to display the way I want them to.

Any ideas on how this could work?

Comment: Are the arrays guaranteed to be the same length?

Comment: Yes, the arrays are guaranteed to be the same length.

Comment: you can create custom directive

Comment: The code you've provided looks fine.  As long as each row has a consistent height, they will line up fine.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution:

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="item in array1">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6"><h1 class="col-*-12">Array 1 values</h1>

            <div class="col-*-12">{{array1[$index].value}}</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6"><h1 class="col-*-12">Array 2 values</h1>

            <div class="col-*-12">{{array2[$index].value}}</div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm guessing this is a single joined array solution?  Also, doesn't this repeat the titles for each item in the array?

Comment: I had a typo in my answer, second array1 should have been array2. Hopefully this answers yours questions - that is not a joined array solution and it won't repeat the output.